# Custom header has nil outlets

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using the following code for my custom header and the objects within the cell are nil. I have tried to reconnect the outlets and use a uiview instead of a tableviewcell, but nothing changed. The cell is located inside a tableview that is in a uiviewcontroller.

```
class CaptionHeaderCell: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var typeField: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusField: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeField: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CaptionHeaderCell", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CaptionHeaderCell")
    self.tableView.register(CaptionHeaderCell.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CaptionHeaderCell")

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CaptionHeaderCell") as! CaptionHeaderCell

//Crashes when trying to set text
            header.timeField.text = self.getCallTime(startTime: call!.startTime, endTime: call!.endTime)

        return header
    }
```

Hierarchy of view:
[image]
]

Objects connected:
[image]

Nil when referenced in viewForHeaderInSection:
[image]

Comment: If its in the controller you don't need to register, just give a reuse identifier in storyboard and use it in your controller. If you want the header view to be used in other controller then you have to create a separate xib.

Comment: Could you post the crash logs?

Comment: I have tried removing the register but then the cell instance is nil.

Answer (score 1):

In my project I haven't added this line of code:

```
self.tableView.register(CaptionHeaderCell.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CaptionHeaderCell")
```

I have created the cell directly in :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

and that too not as a `HeaderFooterview`.

I added below line of code and it worked:

```
var headerView: CaptionHeaderCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CaptionHeaderCell") as? CaptionHeaderCell
```

Try if it works in your scenario.

Comment: are you using a uitableviewcell or a uiview? if you are using a cell, are you getting nil references to the object on the view? If you are using a uiview, how are you setting the identifier?

Comment: Using `uitableviewcell` and not getting nil reference.

Comment: I originally had it has uitableviewcell and it was working great but I needed to change it because I have to update a value on the header at a later time and I couldn't properly reference it without reloading the entire section

Comment: Try adding this line of code: `if (headerView == nil)
        {
            headerView = CaptionHeaderCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:"CaptionHeaderCell")
        }` to handle nil condition.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm using this code:

```
func register<T: UITableViewHeaderFooterView>(_ classType: T.Type) {
    let desc = String(describing: classType)
    register(classType, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: desc)
}
```

I got nil references too, but if change to:

```
func register<T: UITableViewHeaderFooterView>(_ classType: T.Type) {
    let desc = String(describing: classType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: desc, bundle: nil)
    register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: desc)
}
```

Everything is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

for me nothing worked, the solution was to use UITableViewCell instead of UITableViewHeaderFooterView my code was more or less like this ..

-**Component**-

```
class TitleHeaderDetails: UITableViewCell{

// MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imgLine: UIImageView!

// MARK: - Lifeecycle
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
}
```

}

-**in viewDidLoad**-

```
registerCell(tableView: tableView, cellType: TitleHeaderDetails.self)
```

-**in RegisterCell**-
add in your class

```
 static func registerCellNib<T: UITableViewCell>(_ tableView: UITableView, cellType: T.Type)

public func registerCell(tableView: UITableView, cellType: Any){
    YourClass.registerCellNib(tableView, cellType: cellType as! UITableViewCell.Type)
}
```

-**in Delegate**-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

-**viewForHeaderInSection**-

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let viewForHeader = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 40))
    
    let titleHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TitleHeaderDetails") as! TitleHeaderDetails
    titleHeader.frame = viewForHeader.bounds
  
    viewForHeader.addSubview(titleHeader)
    
    return titleHeader
}
```

-**My Result**-
[image]